# yii making rating system - what is better practice for calculating average rating

Tags: php, mysql, yii, rating-system

I would like to make ratings on our classified ads. We have classified and ratings models. When user rates an advertisement it is recorded to ratings database with userid advertisement_id and rating.

What is the best approach to calculate average ratings for advertisement?

I see two options:

1. Through relations (with dbCriteria,scope) calculate average ratings for advertisement on the go, while displaying.
2. Calculate sum of ratings and count of ratings and save it in advertisement db everytime anyone creates or updates rating. In this case, if inserting new i would add to the sum the rating and add +1 to the count; if updating i would add the change of rating and leave count unaffected.

Method two would be faster in my opinion, but what is better practice?

Comment: Method 2 is better on so many levels that you don't even have to waste 1 microsecond of your time thinking about method 1.

Comment: If you have a lot of ratings a third option could be a cron (or using a queue if you have one in your application) that update the average in the db each hour or each days.
The main advantage is that the operation is not performed during the user request so you gain some time to display the webpage

Comment: While method 2 is *faster* unless the average operation is really slowing your website down, (if you have many and frequenet queries for this data try query caching first) storing it in seperate db/table/field is anti-pattern and it can create data integrity if you don't recompute the values each time an underlying data/BL changes for example what if your user changes his rating, or deletes a rating, or is banned etc you will need to recompute carefully and factor each case. Unless you have exhausted the easier optimization techniques you should try not to de-normalizing data.